# Trouble with shared preferences, saving a int variable

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

Hi I'm having trouble with sharedpreferences and saving the data of a int, I've tried everything but I can't figure it out.

Im using getExtra from two seperate activities to pull that data to the main activity and then adding those variables together to give me a total. Im trying to make it so that when leaving the main activity that all the variable stays the same and updates when the other two activites are changed.

this is the main activity with the sharedpreferences

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    YearOneActivityButton();
    YearTwoActivityButton();

    SharedPreferences totalScorePref = getSharedPreferences("TotalScorePref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    scoreTotal = totalScorePref.getInt("TotalScoreY1", 0);

    Intent totalGradeValueY1 = getIntent();
    Intent totalGradeValueY2 = getIntent();

    int year2Score = totalGradeValueY2.getIntExtra("totalYearValueY2", 0);
    int year1Score = totalGradeValueY1.getIntExtra("totalYearValueY1", 0);

    scoreTotal = year1Score + year2Score;

    numberScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_score_txt);
    numberScore.setText(String.valueOf(year1Score));

    numberScore1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_score_1_txt);
    numberScore1.setText(String.valueOf(year2Score));

    totalGradeTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total_grade_txt);
    totalGradeTxt.setText(String.valueOf(scoreTotal));

    Log.d("SCORETOTAL", String.valueOf(scoreTotal));

}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    int pTotalScore = scoreTotal;

    SharedPreferences totalScorePref = getSharedPreferences("TotalScorePref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = totalScorePref.edit();
    editor.putInt("TotalScoreY1", pTotalScore);

    editor.commit();

    super.onPause();
}
```

}

this is how im passing the data

```
public void SubmitMainActivity() {
    ButtonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
    ButtonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int totalGradeValueY1 = totalAllSpinnerValuesY1;
            Intent year1ScoreIntent = new Intent(YearOneActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            year1ScoreIntent.putExtra("totalYearValueY1", totalGradeValueY1);
            startActivity(year1ScoreIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try like this

```
SharedPreferences topic = getSharedPreferences("topicfun", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor topiccom = topic.edit();
topiccom.putInt("topicname",10);
topiccom.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add below code after you calculate the **totalGradeTxt**:

```
SharedPreferences totalScorePref = getSharedPreferences("TotalScorePref", 
                                                    MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = totalScorePref
                                          .edit()
                                          .putInt("TotalScoreY1",pTotalScore)
                                          .apply();
```

> NOTE: I have used apply() instead of commit()

Comment: thanks for replying, just tried this still not working, it feels like it shouldnt be this hard.

i moved the "editor = totalscorepref" below the "scoreTotal = year1Score + year2Score"

but still getting same results, not saving the variable as the textview are not being saved.